# vb6 to upgrade vb.net prblem

Tags: vb.net, migration, vb6-migration

I converted my project from vb6 to vb.net

In vb6 project i created 3 user controls (for LED DISPLAY CONTROL)

I upgraded project to vb.net in .net 3.5.

I fixed all bugs that comes from upgrade issue.

But now while **loading the user control on form it takes too much time**

Is there any way for code optimization or anything else so that I can load user control on my form as **fast** as on vb6 form

Also my CPU utilization increases very much up to 90%

What is the reason behind this .

Comment: Can you post a snippet of the slow code ?

Comment: LedBoard.DrawBoard()
It contains LedBoard user control DrawBoard method in it.In drawBoard method it calls another controls method..This also called another control.So that consecutively **3 times**  it calls one another controls and also in that get executed many times in loop but it gets executed in vb6 properly but what about vb.net

Comment: What **code changes** should be made in upgradation of vb6 to vb.net

Comment: Impossible to answer without any code sample

Answer (score 0):

Poor conversion. I have yet to see any decent sized VB6 to .NET converted code perform well without manual optimization after the conversion. Events fire differently in .NET and there are different events that may be better to use than what was used in VB6; events are likely the underlying problem. You need to post the code if you want better answers.

Answer (score 0):

Probably the user controls are being loaded and executed in different order and maybe a different number of times than in VB6. Add some breakpoints to see when each control is being initialized (and how many times), and make sure everything runs in the same order as it did in VB6.

Also, make sure there are no events, in user OR Windows controls, being called during form initialization.